# Bash script that copies the differences in two directories to a third directory?

Tags: bash, shell

What I want to do is compare two directories, d1 and d2, and copy all files that are not present in both d1 & d2 to a third directory, d3.

I know that I can copy all files in both directories using this:

> cp -vfudp dir1/* dir3/
>
> cp -vfudp dir2/* dir3/

But I know I need to incorporate the find function and compare. Or diff. Could I use

> rsync -a dir1/ dir2/

to somehow create a third directory and put the differences?

I think I need to use

> diff -r --brief dir1 dir2

somewhere in there too. I'm a novice programmer, and new to bash too, so explanations with the functions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(diff dir1 dir2 | sed 's/Only in \([^ ]*\): /\1\//'); do
    cp "$file" dir3/
done
```

`diff dir1 dir2` gives you a list of files that are not present in both directories:

```
$ diff dir1 dir2
> Only in dir2: f3
> Only in dir1: f4
> Only in dir2: f5
```

We pipe this through [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to get only the path to the file (maybe `diff` has an option to do this and we don't need [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ diff dir1 dir2 | sed 's/Only in \([^ ]*\): /\1\//'
> dir2/f3
> dir1/f4
> dir2/f5
```

Then we loop over this list of files and copy them to `dir3`.

Careful with subdirectories! (Do you have any?)

Let's have a closer look at the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command:

```
sed 's/Only in \([^ ]*\): /\1\//'
```

`s` is the substitute command, if you e.g. want to substitute true with false, you'd use `s/true/false/`. We want to substitute `Only in \([^ ]*\):`. The first part is just the output text from the `diff` command, then we use the escaped brackets `\(` and `\)` to match the name of the file, in order to reference to it later again (with `\1`). Inside the brackets we have `[^ ]*`, which matches everything except a space (so here we are assuming that the filenames have no spaces, this could be improved!). This matches the name of the directory. Then we match some more text of the `diff` command, namely `:`. All this is replaced with `\1`, which is just the part inside `\(` and `\)` (the name of the directory). We end up with the full path to the file in question.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm reading up on sed right now to understand more, but I'm assuming no subdirectories. The first bit of code makes sense, I just don't understand this bit: 

>'s/Only in \([^ ]*\): /\1\//'

Comment: I added an explanation of the [tag:sed] command. Reading and explaining the syntax of [tag:sed] can be difficult, so I'd suggest to do a tutorial if you're interested in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1="/tmp/d1"
d2="/tmp/d2"
d3="/tmp/d3"

cd "${d1}"
for file in * ; do
    if [ ! -f "${d2}/${file}" ] ; then
        cp "${file}" "${d3}"
    fi
done
cd -

cd "${d2}"
for file in * ; do
    if [ ! -f "${d1}/${file}" ] ; then
        cp "${file}" "${d3}"
    fi
done
cd -
```

Answer (score 0):

### A one liner solution using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and [diff](/questions/tagged/diff)

```
LANG=C diff -aqr /tmp/d1 /tmp/d2 |
    awk -F'[ :]' '/^Only in/{system("cp -a "$3"/"$NF " /tmp/d3/")}'
```

### Explanations

- `LANG=C` force diff output to be in English for erliable parsing
- `diff -aqr /tmp/d1 /tmp/d2` will display the files that are missing or different from both dirs recursively
- we use `awk` to cut out the dir/filenames
- `-F'[ :]'` means : spliting columns on spaces and `:`
- '/^Only in/`is like a`grep`, and if the pattern is found, we execute :
- `system("cp -a "$3"/"$NF " /tmp/d3/")` : copy found_dir/found_file in /tmp/d3

### Warning

- the script don't handle file/dir with space in names, this require extra processing, but you have a good start now

Comment: This one is the shortest, could you provide a short explanation on what awk does here?