# Common files in 2 directories

Tags: bash, perl, shell, unix

I've 2 directories dir1 and dir2 containing more than 8000 files each. I want to extract the files from dir1 that has same name in dir 2 to one directory and also the files in dir2 that has the same name in dir1 into another directory.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It sounds a bit as if you want to have: (1) dir1/fileA and dir2/fileA both exist, and (2) you want to move dir1/fileA to dir3/fileA, and (3) you want to move dir2/fileA to dir4/fileA.  Is that what you're seeking?  If so, please say so in the question.  If not, please explain what you do want in more detail.

Comment: Also, what did you try?  There are many questions on StackOverflow which are simiar or variants of your scenario; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644593/unix-compare-two-folders-which-has-many-files-inside-contents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014987/bash-script-that-copies-the-differences-in-two-directories-to-a-third-directory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019857/diff-files-present-in-two-different-directories, etc

Comment: Yep..exactly what you have explained. Here is a point to note - the files with same name in 2 directories contains different content. That's why I want to extract the files in dir1 that have same name with dir2 files to dir3 and similarly dir2 files that have same name with dir1 files to dir4.

Comment: Erm, you have duplicates in your duplicates so you want to duplicate the duplicates?  Yo, dawg.

Comment: Of course the statement is appropriate for the file names. **But as I've mentioned the content is different in both files that have same name.**

Comment: What good will this do? You already have the files. How does it help to have another copy of the files in `dir3` and `dir4`?

Comment: that's where my work starts..after having files in dir3 and dir4, I will append the sequence present in the dir3 files to the files of dir4 keeping in mind that **I am appending the sequence of file1(file name) of dir3 to the sequence of file1(file name) of dir4** . Then further analysis starts..

Comment: The clarification comments here would be best to merge into the original question - comments are ephemeral, and it would be useful to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1list=(/path/to/dir1/*)
dir2list=(/path/to/dir2/*)

mkdir /tmp/dirlist

for(( n=0; n<${#dir1list}; n++)); do
   echo "${dir1list[n]##/*/}" >> /tmp/dirlist/dir1.list
done

for(( n=0; n<${#dir2list}; n++)); do
   echo "${dir2list[n]##/*/}" >> /tmp/dirlist/dir2.list
done

grep -Fx -f /tmp/dirlist/dir2.list /tmp/dirlist/dir1.list > /tmp/dirlist/difflist1.txt

grep -Fx -f /tmp/dirlist/dir1.list /tmp/dirlist/dir2.list > /tmp/dirlist/difflist2.txt

XIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
Difflist1=($(</tmp/dirlist/difflist1.txt))
Difflist2=($(</tmp/dirlist/difflist2.txt))
IFS=$XIFS

for(( n=0; n<${#Difflist1}; n++)); do
   mv "/path/to/dir1/${Difflist1[n]}" /path/to/dir3
done

for(( n=0; n<${#Difflist2}; n++)); do
   mv "/path/to/dir2/${Difflist2[n]}" /path/to/dir4
done
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this. I based this off of a much more complicated script I had to write a few months ago, so it may not be optimized for your specific job.

Comment: Thank you..that's enough for me..I can modify it for my problem::

Comment: You're welcome. All you need to do is change the /path/to/dir's and it should work as is. Just paste it into a file, fix the dir paths, chmod +x and run. Note: I tested it on my computer and the pathnames needed to be the full name (i.e. ~/dir did not work in some places)

Comment: See also fdupes, although it doesn't have the ability to move files into multiple directories. It's good for finding duplicate files, and optionally eliminating all but the first found duplicate.

Comment: I'll have too look into that. I would usually use cmp for that.